# Open two resultsets simultaneously

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to do this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt(1);

    ResultSet innerRs = stmt.executeQuery("select something from sometable where id =" + id + ";");

    String one = innerRs.getString(1);
    String two = rs.getString(2);    //result set is already closed thrown here. 

}
```

but I am getting the error "result set already closed". I am using Postgresql. I can't really figure out another way to do this that isn't very labour intensive. How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need two resultsets. Just [learn](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the [SQL JOIN clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) so that you can get the desired data from two different tables in a single SQL query.

If you *really* need to, then creating a separate statement instead of reusing an existing one is indeed the way to go. Reusing it would namely force all previously opened cursors (resultsets) to be closed.

Comment: I think the join may be ideal, thanks. Will implement it and see.

Comment: @providence it may be best for the join (ill admit i didnt read your string), but the answer to why you are getting the error is the resultset closed I posted as the first answer.  Good to know if you encounter this in the future.  I had a similar problem writing an interface between 2 separate DBMS :)

Comment: brilliant, this did the trick. Always glad to learn of features like this one! Also, thank you @rayman86 for explaining the nature of the error! that knowledge will definately come in handy at some point +1

Comment: @providence: you're welcome. @ray: yes, your answer already got a vote. By the way, how would 2 separate DBMS ever share the same statement?

Comment: Well they didnt.  The statement was for a single dmbs, but i needed the resultset to modify some in the other and run more queries on the first, so when I tried to re-use the statement I got the error.  I ended up using 3 statements but the attempted re-use was the experience that showed me this :)

Answer (score 3):

You use `stmt.executeQuery()`, did you use `stmt` to execute `rs`?  If so, you need a new `statement` as creating a query on one you used already forces it to close, resulting in this error.